# Maven test - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.testng.AssertJUnit

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit

I'm trying this [guide](https://www.guru99.com/maven-jenkins-with-selenium-complete-tutorial.html#3) to learn to integrate Maven, Jenkins and Selenium. The issue with guides is the erosion of time and serious compatibility issues. I've been trying to debug it as I go, but right now I'm at step 15 and can't go further due to this issue:

> T E S T S
> ------------------------------------------------------- Running example.NewTest Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time
> elapsed: 2.255 sec <<< FAILURE!
>
> Results :
>
> Failed tests:   example.NewTest.testEasy(): org/testng/AssertJUnit
>
> Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
>
> [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 9.145s [INFO] Finished at: Tue Sep 12 09:42:36 PDT
> 2017 [INFO] Final Memory: 7M/17M [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12:test
> (default-test) on project WDTest: There are test failures. [ERROR]
> [ERROR] Please refer to
> C:\ST\kpimuiws-build-changes\WDTest\target\surefire-reports for the
> individual test results.

The surefire reports textfile shows:

> Test set: example.NewTest
>
> Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.255 sec <<< FAILURE! example.NewTest.testEasy()  Time elapsed: 2.25 sec
>
> <<< FAILURE! java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/testng/AssertJUnit
> at example.NewTest.testEasy(NewTest.java:34) Caused by:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.testng.AssertJUnit
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)  at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
> sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   ... 19 more

Here is my pom;

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>WDTest</groupId>
  <artifactId>WDTest</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>            
        <dependency>                
             <groupId>junit</groupId>                               
             <artifactId>junit</artifactId>                             
             <version>3.8.1</version>                               
             <scope>compile</scope>                             
        </dependency>               
        <dependency>                
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>                              
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>                              
            <version>2.45.0</version>                               
        </dependency>       
                
</dependencies>
</project>
```

and here is my NewTest.java

```
package example;        

import java.io.File;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
//import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.AssertJUnit;
//import org.openqa.selenium.By;        
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;       
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;       
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
//import org.testng.annotations.Test;   
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;   
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;        






public class NewTest {      
        //private WebDriver driver;     
        
        File pathBinary = new File("C:\\Users\\T667627\\AppData\\Local\\MozillaFirefox\\firefox.exe");
        FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary = new FirefoxBinary(pathBinary);
        FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();       
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxBinary, firefoxProfile);
        
        @Test               
        public void testEasy() {    
            driver.get("http://demo.guru99.com/selenium/guru99home/");  
            String title = driver.getTitle();                
            AssertJUnit.assertTrue(title.contains("Demo Guru99 Page"));         
        }   
        @BeforeTest
        public void beforeTest() {  
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();  
        }       
        @AfterTest
        public void afterTest() {
            driver.quit();          
        }       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AssertJUnit is part of the TestNG library.  Can you try including TestnG in your POM?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.11</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: That worked! First time really working with all of the technologies, but still don't know how I overlooked that dependency. Thank you!